# Batch script to convert .rej to CSV in order to parse useful data

Tags: powershell, batch-file

The aim is to search multiple files with the extension of .rej, So i have a file that can easily display that information.

So I went in a completely different direction and uses CSV's because the info I needed is only 3 strings on every line.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
For %%I in (*.rej) do (
    (for /f "delims==" %%A in (%%I) do set string=%%A & echo !string::=,!) >> %%~nI_Tempout.tmp
    (for /f "delims==" %%A in (%%~nI_Tempout.tmp) do set string=%%A & echo !string:[=,!) >> %%~nI_Tempout1.tmp
    (for /f "delims=" %%A in (%%~nI_Tempout1.tmp) do Call :Split %%A ) > %%~nI_New.csv)
    goto :Eof
    :Split
@echo(%1,%9,%11
del *.tmp
```

File.rej

```
12.13.14 [-]  [20190304][ VBTS 0 ] REJECTED:IM:2q1231231123124:II:123123123123:TM:1278391237912379128379:CAUSES:
12.13.16 [-]  [20190304][ VBTS 0 ] REJECTED:IM:2q1231231123124:II:123123123123:TM:1278391237912379128379:CAUSES:
12.13.20 [-]  [20190304][ VBTS 0 ] REJECTED:IM:2q1231231123124:II:123123123123:TM:1278391237912379128379:CAUSES:
```

However at the end the %11 prints %1 the 1,
I can only assume it detects %1 the echos the next 1

output

```
12.13.14,2q1231231123124,12.13.141
12.13.16,2q1231231123124,12.13.161
12.13.20,2q1231231123124,12.13.201
```

FINAL CODE

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
For %%I in (*.rej) do (
    (for /f "delims==" %%A in (%%I) do set string=%%A & echo !string::=,!) >> %%~nI_Tempout.tmp
    (for /f "delims==" %%A in (%%~nI_Tempout.tmp) do set string=%%A & echo !string:[=,!) >> %%~nI_Tempout1.tmp
    (for /f "tokens=1,8,10 delims=," %%A in (%%~nI_Tempout1.tmp) do Call :Split %%A %%B %%C ) > %%~nI_New.csv)
    goto :Eof
    :Split
@echo(%1,%2,%3
del *.tmp
```

Comment: In order to help you with your code, we really need to see it, otherwise you're simply asking us to do your work for you, _whilst you sit back and relax!_

Comment: I suggest to concentrate on one script language (as presumably Regular Expressions are involved better choose PowerShell) and present your code in a [mcve] even if not working. Also sample lines of your input files and expected output.

Comment: replace your last `for` with `(for /f "tokens=1,9,11 delims=," %%A in (%%~nI_Tempout1.tmp) do Call :Split %%A %%B %%C ) > %%~nI_New.csv` and in your subroutine do `@echo(%1,%2,%3` (adapt the tokens to your needs; I doubt you need `CAUSES` as the last one)

Comment: And what about just `(for /f "tokens=1,7,11 delims=[-]: " %%A in ('type *.rej 2^>nul') do echo %%A,%%B,%%C)>file_New.csv`? (Single-Line solution without temp files)

Comment: Wow that was so fast and it works perfectly,

Answer (score 0):

You parse your data to a temp file, parse that a second time to a second temp file and parse that a third time. That is inefficient. You can do it all with a single `for /f` loop, when you choose your tokens and delims wisely:

```
(for /f "tokens=1,7,11 delims=[-]: " %%A in ('type *.rej 2^>nul') do echo %%A,%%B,%%C)>file_New.csv
```

I'm not quite sure, if the tokens are right, because you didn't show your expected output, but you can easily adapt them to your needs.